# TFS 2013 | Building Issues with many Solutions | Vb.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, tfs, build

Hi fellow Stackoverflowers!

To clear things up: I'm pretty new to TFS and I really try to set it up right, but can't get it to work.

## Setup

I am part of a team, that generally develops all internal tools for our company.
Those tools are not gathered in a single Solution, each one has its own Solution and now we have got exactly 116 Solutions/Folders on a Network Share.
Those Solutions are not part of any source safe or are version controlled anywhere.
So we had the idea to set up TFS for our Solutions to get some version control and keep track of changes with opportunities for branching and everything the TFS offers.
I could set up everything needed for the TFS, but now I am stuck at the point when it comes to building and dropping.

Currently we have 2 different Network Shares - 1 where our "Source Code" is and 1 where our binaries go, where they will be called later.

To be honest - I hate that setup, but I can not change it and have to deal with the following problem.

## Problem

So current state is, that every Solution is part of the TFS-SourceControl.
If now a developer checks out something, changes something and checks-in again, it would not be a problem to trigger a build.

**1)** 
But most of our Solutions rely on a certain assembly that is developed inhouse. That assembly can not be build by any of us developers, because it was builded with a certain password in cleartext in sourcecode and afterwards the password got deleted and the solution got safed. So basically the assembly is static as it is.

**2)** The next thing is, that after building the checked in Solution(s) they should be copied to our Network Share, where our binaries are stored.

**3)** After creating a Single Build Definition, I was not sure how to set it up, so that every solution/project that was touched is built, not everything. I was pretty confused after i read more then once, that i really need 116 Build Definitions (and add more, when tools are added)

## What to do?

I am really frustrated, because I can't figure out the right way to do that. After searching and reading, I read that I should stay away from adding the required binaries to the source control. After that I looked for a way to enforce a local build on Check-In and with a build definition that triggers a script copy files to the right Network Path.
After thinking about that, I decided to come here and ask for help, because it sounds so ridicoulus that I guessed maybe someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether a Check-in triggers a build depends on the build trigger you choose in build definition：

[image]

1) For the assembly. As it's "shared", you can publish it to a package manager such as NuGet or host your own NuGet feeds. Check

- [Creating and Publishing a Package](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package)
- [Hosting Your Own NuGet Feeds](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds)

2) Just like you need a workspace on your dev machine to develop your app, you must specify the workspace that the build agent uses to build and test your app. During the build process, the build agent downloads the files from folders on your version control server into a local working directory.

When you create your build definition, on the **Source Setting** tab, you specify the folders that contain the files that you want to download and how these folders should be mapped to local folders on the build agent. Check [Understand how a build workspace works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh190721%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

3) In the **Projects** box under **Build** in the **Build process parameters** table, you can specify one or more solutions or code projects to build. Check [Build your Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547(v=vs.120).aspx).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Since my question seems to be a "bad"-question I mark your answer as the right one. I now truely understand build workspace and could manage to build only the projects modified. Sadly it seems like I have to create 116 Build definitions but I guess it's better than nothing.
The thing with assemblies is something I don't understand right now, but I guess I have to do more reading so this works out. ATM I included a "Libs"-Folder in TFS to copy while building and this work.